# How to convert Oracle triggers to mysql

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, triggers

This is oracle trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SW_TARIFF_TARIFF_TRIGGER" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF "LAST_UPDATED_DT" ON "DEMO_DB"."SOLID_WASTE_TARIFF_MASTER" 
REFERENCING OLD AS "OLD" NEW AS "NEW" 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN   
    :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DT := SYSDATE; 
END;
```

I want to move it to mysql. But i don't know know i write cretae and replace with one trigger and also have problem with mysql replacement for of keyword of oracle . Can any one suggest me how to convert this oracle trigger to mysql .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySql you need to create two separate triggers, a first trigger `BEFORE INSERT` and a second trigger `BEFORE UPDATE`.
MySql doesn't support this clause `UPDATE OF column_name` - that is the trigger is fired only when a change of the specified column occured. In MySql the trigger is always fired, and You need to detect this condition yourself in a body of the trugger.
Try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SW_TARIFF_TARIFF_TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT ON SOLID_WASTE_TARIFF_MASTER
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DT := Now();
```

and this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SW_TARIFF_TARIFF_TRIGGER2 
BEFORE UPDATE ON SOLID_WASTE_TARIFF_MASTER
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   IF NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DT <> OLD.LAST_UPDATED_DT
      AND NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DT IS NOT NULL
      AND OLD.LAST_UPDATED_DT IS NOT NULL
      OR NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DT IS  NULL AND OLD.LAST_UPDATED_DT IS NOT NULL
      OR NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DT IS NOT NULL AND OLD.LAST_UPDATED_DT IS  NULL
   THEN
       SET NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DT := Now();
   END IF;
END;
```

This horrible IF condition detects if the column `LAST_UPDATED` has been changed (it simulates `UPDATE OF "LAST_UPDATED_DT"` clause from Oracle) 
Please refer to the documentation for more information about triggers in MySql:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html